# dbatools start-dbamigration running very slowly

Tags: sql-server, dbatools

I am trying to use the powershell module dbatools to migrate one SQL Server instance to a new instance on a VM. The new VM is on a different physical server than the source. I am not migrating the databases as I already have restored them on the new instance.

I am using the start-dbamigration task, but it seems to be running very slow. I started it last night at 20:00 hours, and as of writing this (the next day at 09:30), it is still running.

SQL Server version is 2014.
I am running dbatools from my personal PC and was wondering if that could have anything to do with the slowness?

The server has a lot of logins, and it seems that much time goes to granting CONNECT access to the different databases (takes around 40 - 50 seconds per login per database).(This task is called Update-SqlPermission in the log)

Anyone have experience with this tool and know if this is normal or not?
Would it be better to install dbatools on one of the servers?

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the code for each Copy command used in the `Start-DbaMigration` command and try running them each individually (for the objects you want to migrate).

Overall the start command can take some time to run as it does a good bit of extra stuff in the command. Using each Copy command individually is the common method when you are not performing a full migration (including databases).

If you find any particular bugs or slowness you can get further assistance with issues by submitting an issue on our repository [here](https://dbatools.io/issues).